# Las Vergnas theorem - do vertices need to be ordered by their degree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm learning graph theory and I'm not sure one thing about the Las Vergnas theorem.  Do vertices need to be ordered by their degree?

Las Vergnas theorem: $G$ is a graph and $V(G)=(v_1,...,v_n)$. There is no such $i,j$ such that $i<j, i+j \geq n, v_iv_j \notin E(G),
deg(v_i) \leq i, deg(v_j) \leq j-1, deg(v_i) + deg(v_j) \leq n-1$. Then $G$ is hamiltonian

Thanks

Comment: What does the theorem say? Could you please write it down in the question post?

Comment: @Arthur I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Las Vergnas theorem states that if there exists an arrangement of vertices $x_1, \dots, x_n$ of the graph $G$ such that for all $i, j$:

if
$$1 \leq i < j \leq n, \hspace{1cm} i+j \geq n, \hspace{1cm} x_ix_j \notin E(G),$$
$$\text{d}(x_i) \leq i,\hspace{0.5cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{d}(x_j) \leq j-1$$
then
$$\text{d}(x_i)+\text{d}(x_j) \geq n $$

then the graph $G$ is Hamiltonian. To answer the question, that means that the vertices do not need to be ordered by their degree - there must only exist at least one arrangement of the vertices for which the condition holds.